# "Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this' " while forwarding an event

Tags: c#, events, handler

Im trying to forward an event `OnClientMessage` from my class `Client` over the class `Server` to outside my libary.

**Client.cs**

```
public class Client
{
    private TcpClient tcpClient;
    private StreamWriter writer;
    private Boolean alive = true;
    private int id;

    public delegate void OnClientMessageHandler(Client sender, String message);
    public delegate void OnClientDisconnectHandler(Client sender);

    public event OnClientMessageHandler OnClientMessage;
    public event OnClientDisconnectHandler OnClientDisconnect;

    public Client(TcpClient tcpClient, int id)
    {
        this.tcpClient = tcpClient;
        this.id = id;

        writer = new StreamWriter(tcpClient.GetStream());

        new Thread(() =>
        {
            Listen(new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream()));
        }).Start();
    }

    void Listen(StreamReader reader)
    {
        while (tcpClient.GetStream().DataAvailable && alive)
        {
           OnClientMessage(this, reader.ReadLine());
           Thread.Sleep(150);
        }
    }

    public void Write(String message)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(message);
        writer.Flush();
    }

    public int GetID()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        alive = false;
        writer.Close();
        tcpClient.Close();
        OnClientDisconnect(this);
    }
}
```

**Server.cs**

```
public class Server
{
    private IPAddress serverIP;
    private short serverPort;

    private TcpListener serverListener;
    private int serverClientCount;
    public List<Client> serverClients = new List<Client>();

    private Boolean running;

    public delegate void OnClientMessageHandler(Client sender, String message);
    public delegate void OnClientDisconnectHandler(Client sender);

    public event OnClientMessageHandler OnClientMessage;
    public event OnClientDisconnectHandler OnClientDisconnect;

    public Server(IPAddress ip, short port, Boolean autoStart = true)
    {
        this.serverIP = ip;
        this.serverPort = port;

        if(autoStart)
            OpenServer();
    }

    public void OpenServer()
    {
        serverListener = new TcpListener(serverIP, serverPort);
        serverListener.Start();
        running = true;

        while (running)
        {
            if (serverListener.Pending())
            {
                TcpClient tcpClient = serverListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                new Thread(() =>
                {
                    Client client;
                    client = new Client(tcpClient, serverClientCount);

                    client.OnClientMessage += new Client.OnClientMessageHandler(OnClientMessage);
                    client.OnClientDisconnect += new Client.OnClientDisconnectHandler(OnClientDisconnect);

                    serverClients.Add(client);
                    serverClientCount++;
                }).Start();
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.Sleep(150);
            }
        }
    }

    public void WriteToClient(Client client, String message)
    {
        client.Write(message);
    }

    public void WriteToAll(String message)
    {
        serverClients.ForEach(client => client.Write(message));
    }

    public void Shutdown()
    {
        running = false;
        serverClients.ForEach(client => client.Close());
        serverListener.Stop();
    }
}
```

Now when the event is firing the application crashes with `Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'`.
Are I'm doing something wrong or isn't this the right way to forward an event?

Comment: You are using the same name for many things. It could have fooled both you or the compiler. Are you sure that `new Client.OnClientMessageHandler(>>>OnClientMessage<<<);` this 'onclientmessage' is a normal method and not an event? Have you tried writing `new Client.OnClientMessageHandler(myobject.OnClientMessage);`? If it's all OK and you have tried, and it still crashes, you will need to show a little more code, because as it is presented now, it looks messy but normal/correct. Problem must be in the mess or code you've not shown.

Comment: If you want to pass a class to other assemblies/classes, they should refer to the same class. So the server should have a reference to the client assembly and use the same class to receive the event.

Comment: @MichaelLiu `client.OnClientMessage += ...` is in the `Client` class. The second `OnClientMessage` is nothing an event with the same name in the `Server` class.

Comment: @Kimmax: You have a variable called `client` inside your `Client` class?

Comment: @MichaelLiu no, from inside the `Server` class

Comment: I added my whole code, I don't know how good this is, this is a learning project

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is pretty unique, never once seen anybody do this.  It is a regression in the .NET Framework, 3.5 gives you a much better exception.  Basic problem is that you made the event subscribe itself.  A simple version to repro that crash:

```
using System;

class Program {
    public static event Action Kaboom;
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Kaboom += new Action(Kaboom);    // 3.5 raises an exception here
        var handler = Kaboom;
        if (handler != null) handler();  // kaboom
    }
}
```

You are not actually "forwarding" the event.  Untangle your names and code.  Add, say, a Fire() method.