# Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'. using EventHandler with an DLL

Tags: c#, dll, event-handling

Hi what I've done is writing an event handler within an DLL that passing over an json string as an argument. So far so good but during runtime I'm receiving the following error:

> Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'.

Within my DLL the code is looking like this:

```
public delegate void JsonEventHandler(Object sender, JsonEventArgs e);

private void stuff() 
{
     //some more code
     JsonEventArgs eva = new JsonEventArgs();
     eva.msg = jsonMsg;
     initializeMeasure(this, eva);
}


public event JsonEventHandler initializeMeasure;


public class JsonEventArgs : EventArgs
{
     public EmoJson msg { get; set; }
}
```

Within my "main" programm I got this:

```
MyDLL.Receiver receiver = new MyDLL.Receiver();

receiver.initializeMeasure += new MyDLL.Receiver.JsonEventHandler(createFolder); // here comes the error
```

And of cause this is the method:

```
public void createFolder(object sender, MyDLL.Receiver.JsonEventArgs e)
{
    //code
}
```

Any suggestion where this error comes from?

Comment: The C# language provides a pretty hard guarantee that *this* cannot be null and it is not [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22887830/17034).  The only somewhat reasonable blind guess is that your code is being called by broken native code or that the DLL you load at runtime is an old version.